# get no results for query. its not true,not false and to null

Tags: php, mysqli

i did some query to check username and password.
when i enter the right data its working ok,
if i put the right email and wrong password its working ok,
when i put a username that do not exist i get no results and white screen. now echo command jump. its looks like its stuck and there is no error.
any idears?

```
if (isset($email) && isset($password)) {
        $query  = "SELECT * ";
                $query .= "FROM users ";
                $query .= "WHERE user_email = '{$email}' ";
                $query .= "LIMIT 1";

                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


                if ($result) {

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        if ($row["user_password"] == $password) {
                            echo json_encode($row);

                        } else {

                            echo ('{"user_id":"0","user_name":"","user_email":"","user_password":"","register_date":"2016-03-05","confirm":"0"}');
                        }

                    }


                } else {
                  echo("error");
                }
    } else {
        echo($result);
        echo("Missing Vars");
    }
```

Comment: You get no output because you're not outputting anything in that case. It goes into the `if ($result)` branch, but there's no content to execute the `while` loop.

Comment: You shouldn't insert a variable directly inside a mysql query to prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that "if ($result)" is true but it never enters the while loop since there are no rows to iterate over. This would lead to a blank screen. Try echoing out what is returned from the database and echoing out each nest to see what gets output. Like the following:

```
if ($result) {
  echo("if $result must be true because I made it in");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo("I made it in the while loop if there are rows in my result");
    if {
      echo("I made it in while's if");
      ...
    } else {
      echo("I made it in while's else");
      ...
    }
  }
} else {
  echo("if $result must be false because I didn't make it in");
  echo("error");
}
```

I bet that using the above example you'll see:

```
if $result must be true because I made it in
```

And that is all you'll see